# Write the number of elements per line of a file and its repetitions with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with all different integer in which each line may have different lenghts, like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
16 7 8
9 10 101 102 13 14
15 6 17 
24 28 31 30 18
```

I would like to print in output the number of elements that a line presents and the number of times there is the same number of elements per lines; the output of this example should be:

```
3 2
5 2
6 1
```

In the first column there are the number of elements per line, in the second the number of lines that presents the same number of elements.

The first line in the file has 5 elements and also the 5th one etc etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print the count for the number of fields:

```
$ awk '{a[NF]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
5 2
6 1
3 2
```

Pipe to `sort` for ordered output:

```
$ awk '{a[NF]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file | sort
3 2
5 2
6 1
```